# How generate random points within cylinder

Tags: matlab, random, montecarlo, cylindrical

how to generate uniformly distributed points within cylinders giving these parameters, Center point denoted as  C, C1 is bottom and C2 is Top and R is Radius. C1=[5.697592e-01, 3.159923e-01, 1.037074e+00];C2=[4.211637e-01, 5.624242e-01, 7.937364e-02];R=5.000000e-01;

```
%the cordinate 
        C1=[5.697592e-01, 3.159923e-01, 1.037074e+00];
        C2=[4.211637e-01, 5.624242e-01, 7.937364e-02];
        N=600;
        CylinderX = rand(1,N);
        CylinderY = rand(1,N);
        CylinderZ = rand(1,N);
        CylinderHeight = norm(C1 - C2);

        for i = 1 : N
            A = [0 0 0 1];
            x = rand;
            y = rand;
            Px = sqrt(x)*R*cos(2*pi*y);
            Py = sqrt(x)*R*sin(2*pi*y);
            Pz = CylinderHeight * rand;
            %I need the coordinate transformation  logic here

            CylinderX(i) = A(1);
            CylinderY(i) = A(2);
            CylinderZ(i) = A(3);
        end
        plot3(CylinderX , CylinderY , CylinderZ ,'G.');hold on;
```

Comment: What is not working and what are you stuck on? What have you tried? It feels a bit like you posted a home-work question. What coordinate transformation should you used?

Comment: It may help if you take your time explain what's your actual result and expected result

Comment: C1 and C2 is the axial coordinate of the cylinder, i want to know to rotate vector in 3d space

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are doing a fine job of sampling an axis-aligned cylinder with the center of one end at the origin.

But your target cylinder is neither axis aligned nor nailed onto the origin.

You need to transform the points you are generating to the proper region in space.

Construct a unit vector in the direction from `C1` to `C2`, and two mutually perpendicular unit normals to it.<sup>1</sup> These three vectors (which I will call `b1`, `b2`, and `b3`) form a basis and the transformed point is

```
p = C1 + (b1 * x + b2 * y + b3 * z)
```

where I have called the unit vector along the axis `b3`.

---

<sup>1</sup> What pair of these you construct is quite arbitrary, and the naive way would be to take a cross product of `b3` with any vector not (anti-)parallel with it to get the first normal direction (`b1`) and then `b3` cross `b1` to get the second normal direction. The only wrinkle is selecting an initial vector not parallel to `b3`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to generate uniformly distributed points within a 3D object like a sphere or a cylinder is to generate uniformly distributed points within a cube and discard any points that lie outside your desired shape.

Comment: While discarding is certaintly a functional appraoch, with the `sqrt(x)` in there he's using an application of the fundamental theorem of sampling and doesn't need to discard.